# diff between folders whilst ignoring filename changes

Tags: bash, macos, diff, git-diff

How can I use diff in terminal but ignore changes in file names?

Currently this is what i'm doing:

```
diff -wrN folder1 folder2 | grep '^>' | wc -l
```

How can I do git diff between two commit ids whilst:

- ignoring file rename
- only look at java files
- ignore specific folder names e.g. folder 'a' and 'b'
- perform the grep '^>' | wc -l

Comment: What, in your mind, does it mean to compare folders when the files are not named the same? If folder1 contains files a, b, and c while folder2 contains x, y, and z, which files should be compared to which other files? Should a be compared against z, or… what? How should this work?

Comment: This is a git repository, does that help in ignoring file name changes?

Comment: It's a git repository, but are you diffing between states of the tree and repository. For example, are you diffing between the current state of your working tree and some commit? From what you wrote, it sounds like you're still diffing between two folders and it's not clear that `git` will make any difference for that. `git diff` does have a `--find-renames` option, but it's not clear if that works for your use case.

Comment: It is a git repo but I thought it would be easier to remove the non-java files and some folders and then create a new git repo with the folders I want to perform the diff (command above) against.. but I realised the changes in the file names will not be tracked in the new git repo.. now somehow I need to use the original git repo

Comment: sorry about the confusion i modified the question

Comment: When a Java file changes its name, it will be refactored and the class name will be changed too. So the content will be changed as well. I think you can skip the requirement in skipping changes in filenames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem unaware of the hardness of this problem, so I'd like to point out why this is so difficult.

Given two directories which are equal in the beginning and both contain, say, 1000 files.  Now you rename, say, 500 files in one of the directories.  Renamings can vary greatly.  A file called `foobar.txt` originally can be named `DSC-3457.orig.jpg` afterwards.  The diff command cannot really find it again without having any idea about what has been renamed into what.

Additionally, a file called `x` could be renamed to `y`, while a file called `y` could be renamed to `x`.  In this case it even is questionable whether this should be regarded a mere renaming or if simply both files' contents have been exchanged.

This all means that in *general* you will have large problems to accomplish this.  Standard tools will not do this out-of-the-box.

This said, I have two aspects I want to point out which might help you.

1. File Sizes

   You can sort all files by their file sizes and then `diff` each pair of the two directories.  This can work perfectly well if all changes you have are *only* renamings and if all files are of different size.  If you have several files of the same size (maybe by pure chance or because they are all of the same format which has a fixed size), you are in trouble again and will have to compare each *possible* pair of the same-size group.
2. Git-Diff

   You mentioned `git-diff` in the tags.  `git` actually keeps a record in case a file is renamed.  So if you intend to use `git diff`, you can rely to some degree on git's ability to detect renamings.  This typically works if a file is removed and added with a new name in one single commit.  If it gets added  with a new name in one commit and then the older version is removed in another commit, this won't work properly.  There is a lot more to learn about renames in `git diff`; see `man git diff` and search for `rename` in this case, there are about a dozen places this gets mentioned, so I won't try to summarize this here myself.

   EDIT: You can use a command like `git diff --find-renames --diff-filter=ACDMTUX` (i. e. you let all kinds of changes pass the filter with the exception of renamings).

Comment: Thanks you so much! I did not realise. I have two folders (check above comment) but I think its better to stick with the original git folder and perform the diff. Could you please look at the edit in the question?

Comment: It is always problematic to change questions later; it quickly becomes an endless chain of answer-change-answer which is not how SO is supposed to work.  You should post a new question regarding your new topic "java files only".  For filtering out all renaming actions (i. e. the ones git detected), please see my edit in my answer above.

Comment: Don't feel sorry :)  Welcome to Stackoverflow!  Everybody here started sometime.